# Converting jsx with ES6 import syntax using reactify

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, ecmascript-6

I am using reactify (a browserify transform https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify) to convert JSX to regular JS.
I have setup a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('reactifyes6', function () {
    var bundler = watchify(browserify(watchify.args));
    return bundler.add('./Scripts/Widget/ReactComponents/Dashboard.jsx')
    .transform('reactify',{harmony:true, es6module:true})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('Dashboard.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts/Widget/Build/'));
});
```

For the sake of getting this working I have two files: `Dashboard.jsx` and `someJS.js`.
**Dashboad.jsx**

```
import myFunc from './someJS.js';
myFunc();
```

**someJS.js**

```
export default function () { console.log('test'); };
```

When I run the gulp task `'reactifyes6'`, I get a `ReactifyError "Illegal import declaration while parsing file: [path to my file]"`

What am I doing wrong and how could I compile ES6 import / export syntax?

Comment: You might be better off using babel for the transformation. https://babeljs.io

Comment: Exactly, in this case you should use babel to transform your code, here is an example: http://4dev.tech/2015/12/how-to-use-es6-very-simple-example/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try babelify in place of reactify